# Executing non blocking queries/commands in OrientDB server functions

Tags: orientdb

Is there anyway we can execute an asynchronous query or a command on OrientDB server functions (JavaScript)?
e.g. to do something like

```
db.query('UPDATE User SET password...');
db.asyncQuery('INSERT INTO Log...');
```

ODB Java API seems to be supporting this by OSQLAsynchQuery but I could not find a similar ability to do it on server functions.